# How to run a macro when pet battling in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I found a macro to make it easier to cancel pet battles in World of Warcraft.

I put it on action bar. However, when I start a pet battle, my action bar is gone.

How can I execute a macro when doing a pet battle?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've made your macro, bind it to a hotkey, something that won't affect your current hotkeys on your action bars. (You can do this by pressing ESC to bring up the menu).

In the battle, just press the hotkey you bound the macro to.

Comment: To add to this answer: you can also use an addon (like Bartender or Dominos) and show/hide specific action bars in situations like Pet Battle, Vehicle, etc.